# Change active collection

Tags: python, scripting, collections

Is there a way to change the "active" collection?
I can check witch collection is currently selected with this code:

```
>>> bpy.context.collection
bpy.data.collections['My Collection']
```

But I can't change it using this property because is read-only. Is there a way to do that?

---

**EDIT**

After some research I found out **part** of the solution. I can use this code to get and set the active layer collection.

```
# Get the current active layer collection and store it in x
x = bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection
# Select another layer collection from the outliner,
# then use this code to restore x as active
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = x
```

the new problem is that x is not a Collection object, is a LayerCollection and we can't pass any collection created with the method:

```
myColl = bpy.data.collections.new('My Collection')
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(myColl)
```

So the refined question is:
How to obtain a LayerCollection for a particular Collection to change the Active Collection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I could find to obtain the LayerCollection for a particular Collection is to transverse bpy.context.layer_collection looking for the name I want

```
#Recursivly transverse layer_collection for a particular name
def recurLayerCollection(layerColl, collName):
    found = None
    if (layerColl.name == collName):
        return layerColl
    for layer in layerColl.children:
        found = recurLayerCollection(layer, collName)
        if found:
            return found

#Create one collection
myColl = bpy.data.collections.new('My Collection')
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(myColl)

#Create another collection
myColl = bpy.data.collections.new('Another Collection')
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(myColl)

#Change the Active LayerCollection to 'My Collection'
layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection
layerColl = recurLayerCollection(layer_collection, 'My Collection')
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layerColl

#Change the Active LayerCollection to 'Another Collection'
layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection
layerColl = recurLayerCollection(layer_collection, 'Another Collection')
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layerColl
```

Comment: It's weird to have to iterate over all collections to get or set the exclusion state of a particular one...

Comment: @Gorgious but that is the only way currently to also capture nested collections? but it does not solve this problem https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302094/how-can-i-fully-select-a-collection-using-python-with-blue-highlight

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie yes, it also doesn't take into account that a collection can be linked in several layer collections in a single view layer. This solution only selects the first one it found. You might be interested in my discussion over on [devtalk](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/unique-identifier-for-layer-collections/23966)

Answer (score 11):

In Blender 2.80, I've had some success with something simpler that previous [@johnzero7's solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/127700/82339) :

```py
collection = bpy.data.collections.new('My Collection')
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(collection)

# NOTE the use of 'collection.name' to account for potential automatic renaming
layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children[collection.name]
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layer_collection
```

Comment: It doesn't work for collection that is inside another collection, does it?

Comment: That's possible, this answer does not indeed fit a generic "change active collection" solution, it assumes that you created/linked the collection so there's no need for a full search in all layer tree.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying.