# Whats the Blender 2.8 command for adding an object to a collection using python?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, collections

I currently have a method that does:

```
self.myCol = bpy.data.collections.new(self.collection_name)
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(myCol)
```

This method creates and adds a new collection to the outliner. Next, I want to create a bunch of cubes and add those cubes to the collection. How can I tell blender to create objects **only within that particular collection**?

Something like:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(collection='name', size=2, location=(0, 0, 0))
```

Obvious cube_add doesn't have the param for it, so what's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. C is bpy.context btw.

```
self.master_collection = bpy.context.scene.collection

self.layer_collection = bpy.data.collections[ collection_name ]

for i in range(...):

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, view_align=False, enter_editmode=False, location=(0, 0, 0))
    # Create the cubes

    self.layer_collection.objects.link(C.object) #link it with collection

    self.master_collection.objects.unlink(C.object) #unlink it from master collection
```

Answer (score 9):

Your answer is actually wrong.

If your active collection is another as the main collection, when running your script the object will not be removed from this.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
# our created cube is the active one
obj = bpy.context.active_object
# Remove object from all collections not used in a scene
bpy.ops.collection.objects_remove_all()
# add it to our specific collection
bpy.data.collections['MyCollection'].objects.link(obj)
```

About remove all:
https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.ops.collection.html#bpy.ops.collection.objects_remove_all

Answer (score 1):

**Set the active collection.**

IMO the key here if adding a new object with an operator is setting the context collection.  See [Change active collection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127403/change-active-collection)

python console test.

Set the context collection to scene "master collection" `scene.collection` and add cube to it.

```
>>> lc = C.view_layer.layer_collection
>>> C.view_layer.active_layer_collection = lc
>>> C.collection
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].collection

>>> bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
{'FINISHED'}
```

Set to another collection in the scene, *eg* "Collection" in default startup file *ie*  `scene.collection.children['Collection']`

```
>>> lc = C.view_layer.layer_collection.children['Collection']
>>> C.view_layer.active_layer_collection = lc
>>> C.collection
bpy.data.collections['Collection']

>>> bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
```

Answer (score 0):

## OBJ Importing

The script imports .obj files from a specified folder and pastes them to the scene by collections. **Import.py** creates the empty collections and temporary moves objects to data-block. **Paste.py** moves objects from data-block to the scene and distributes them by collections. Also added the scale and rotation corrections.

The important moment that can help with the question happens here: at first the objects creates from the meshes data-block using `bpy.data.objects.new(mesh.name, mesh)` and continue store in the objects data-block (not linked with the scene). After they are distributed across the collections using the name matching.

#### Import.py

```
import bpy
import os.path as path
import glob

root = path.abspath(path.join('' ,".."))
files = glob.glob(root + '\*.obj')

for f in files:
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=f)
    name = path.split(f)[1].replace('.obj', '')
    col = bpy.data.collections.new(name)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(col)
    
    indexes = len([ob for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects if ob.tag == False])
    
    for i in range(indexes):
         bpy.context.selected_objects[i].name = '{}-{}'.format(name, i)
         bpy.context.selected_objects[i].data.name = '{}-{}'.format(name, i)
    
    bpy.ops.collection.objects_remove_all()
    
    for ob in bpy.data.objects:
        bpy.data.objects.remove(ob)
    
    for m in bpy.data.materials:
        m.user_clear()
        bpy.data.materials.remove(m)

for mesh in bpy.data.meshes:
    ob = bpy.data.objects.new(mesh.name, mesh)
    ob.active_material_index = 0
    for i in range(len(ob.material_slots)):
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_remove({'object': ob})
```

#### Paste.py

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Euler
from math import radians

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    for col in bpy.data.collections:
       if col.name == ob.name.split('-')[0]:
            col.objects.link(ob)

for ob in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    ob.scale = Vector=((0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
    ob.rotation_euler = Euler((radians(180), 0.0, 0.0), 'XYZ')
```

**Note:** *DON’T use a symbol `-` in names*