# Python Script to import obj and create collections

Tags: python, scripting, import, collections

I’m having trouble updating a script that worked in Blender 2.7 over to 2.8. Since Scene Layers have been changed over to Collections. The script takes all the OBJ files from a location and brings them into Blender, which is working great.

The issue is after the objects are added to their collections there is also another "linked" copy in the Outliner.

Why is this a problem? I want to hide all the collections apart from the first one. Having these linked objects means when I try and hide the collection the object(s) stay visible.

Does anyone know how I can import objects into a collection without it linking a new copy?

I tried `bpy.ops.object.move_to_collection` function instead of linking objects. But I could not make it work in my script.

Here is the script:

```py
import bpy
import os
import glob

directory_im = 'C:/Users/mila/OneDrive/Desktop/OBJ for test/'
files = glob.glob(directory_im + "*.obj")
for f in files:
    head, tail = os.path.split(f)
    collection_name = tail.replace('.obj', '')
    bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=f)
    myCol = bpy.data.collections.new(collection_name)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(myCol)
    for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        myCol.objects.link(ob)
```

And this is how it looks like after the import:

[image]

Comment: Check this answer which probably can help you updating your script: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146713

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Whats the Blender 2.8 command for adding an object to a collection using python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132112/whats-the-blender-2-8-command-for-adding-an-object-to-a-collection-using-python). You need to keep track of your scene collection and unlink the objects from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess what happens here is that the command `bpy.ops.import_scene.obj` imports the obj files into blender as children of the Scene Collection (i.e. `bpy.context.scene.collection`). This just seems to be the behavior of that import command and there seems to be no parameter of that import command allowing you to change the behavior.

Now, your code creates new collections and *links* the imported obj's to those new collections. Linking means that these obj's are referenced by those new collections *as well as the Scene Collection*.

The point here is that objects can be referenced by as many collections as you want. This effectively allows you to build a graph, not just a tree. That behavior resembles the behavior of layers in Blender version < 2.8.

What you need to do is unlink those obj's from the Scene Collection which you can do by adding an unlink command in your `for` loop:

```
for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    myCol.objects.link(ob)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.unlink(obj)
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your answer. It is exactly what I need!