# How to set active 'Scene Collection'

Tags: python, scripting, collections

How to set active 'Scene Collection'? `bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = bpy.data.collections['Master Collection']` not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set active 'Scene Collection'

```
scene_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = scene_collection
```

Answer (score 3):

You can loop trough all your [first level] collections and set the one you want with it's name

```
collections = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children

for collection in collections:
    if collection.name == "name_of_the_collection_you_want_active":
        bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = collection
```

If you want to loop in all collections looking for "My Collection" and set it active you can use this code [Change active collection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127403/change-active-collection) from johnzero7 :

```
#Recursivly transverse layer_collection for a particular name
def recurLayerCollection(layerColl, collName):
    found = None
    if (layerColl.name == collName):
        return layerColl
    for layer in layerColl.children:
        found = recurLayerCollection(layer, collName)
        if found:
            return found

#Change the Active LayerCollection to 'My Collection'
layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection
layerColl = recurLayerCollection(layer_collection, 'My Collection')
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layerColl
```

Comment: I don't think @cscholl's solution works recursively - e.g. it will only work if the collection is not nested in another collection.

Comment: @ddd : you're right, I've edited the code to add a recursive exemple

Answer (score -1):

```
#Change active collection
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children['Master Collection']
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the code and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.