# How can I exclude a collection from rendering with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

Can anybody help me write a script that excludes certain collections (for rendering)?

In the outliner the tooltip says: `Layer.Collection.exclude` and `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].exclude`, so I've tried things like:

```
bpy.ops.outliner.LayerCollection('Structure').exclude
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].LayerCollection('Structure').exclude
```

The online Python link is here: https://docs.blender.org/api/master/bpy.types.LayerCollection.html#bpy.types.LayerCollection.exclude but I don't know what to do with that information.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use the View Layer**

[image]

From the context view layer

```
>>> C.view_layer.active_layer_collection
bpy.data.scenes['Scene']...LayerCollection

>>> C.view_layer.active_layer_collection.name
'My Leaf 0.0'

>>> C.view_layer.active_layer_collection.exclude
False
```

Alternatively from scene

```
>>> C.scene.view_layers['View Layer'].active_layer_collection
bpy.data.scenes['Scene']...LayerCollection

>>> C.scene.view_layers['View Layer'].active_layer_collection.name
'My Leaf 0.0'

>>> C.scene.view_layers['View Layer'].active_layer_collection.exclude = True
```

Related: **[Change active collection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127403/change-active-collection)**

Answer (score 5):

Today I struggled with the same question. I found out I could just use this in 2.83:

`bpy.context.layer_collection.children['My Collection'].exclude = True`
`bpy.context.layer_collection.children['My Collection'].exclude = False`

Edit: tested in 2.90.1

`bpy.data.collections['My Collection'].hide_render = True;`
`bpy.data.collections['My Collection'].hide_render = False;`

Comment: Thanks, the python tool tips seem to be incredibly hard to infer what the Python API is. I'm sure it was a lot easier to infer in <=2.79

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in 2.9. It's incredibly annoying having an API that constantly changes

Answer (score 1):

Great, thanks. My script now looks like this and works well:

```
def CollControlAll (context, CollList, CollLen):
    layer_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection

    for lay in range(0,CollLen):
        layerColl = recurLayerCollection(layer_collection, CollList[lay])
        bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = layerColl
        layerColl.exclude = False
        layerColl.hide_viewport = False
```