# Trying to turn off (exclude) a collection by name?

Tags: python, collections

How to do this?

I've tried

```
bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection["my_collection"].exclude = False
```

and

```
bpy.context.layer_collection["my_collection"].exclude = False
```

and tried looping through collections:

```
def execute(self, context):
    collections = get_viewport_ordered_collections(bpy.context)
    for c in collections:
          if c.name == "my_collection":
...
```

but the error says `get_viewport_ordered_collections is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

So, it *appears* that you cannot explicitly tell a collection to turn off (exclude or turn off the check box) via Blender's python api. Evidently `.exclude` is not available to be set.

The way I finally managed to do this is by turning off the viewport display of the collection, which in turn turns off the viewport display and render flags of all the objects in the same named collection:

```
bpy.data.collections['My Collection'].hide_viewport = False
bpy.data.collections['Line Art'].hide_render = False
```

Comment: Suggested an edit to: [How can I exclude a collection from rendering with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/142114/31447) (the proper way to do it). I'd recommend use `get('your_collection_name')` instead to avoid our famous index error. Note that using the data block reference (`bpy.data.collections...`) might cause issues if the collection is not part of the current scene. Also `bpy.context` in your q example should be replaced by `context` which is already passed to the method.