# How to "Hide a Collection in viewport" but not "Disable in Viewport" via script in Python

Tags: python, 3d-view

Hi Blender coders and artists.

I am updating one of my add-ons for Blender 2.8 and have run into some  issues finding the appropriate way to hide a collection that is added to my scene.

I want to deselect the eyeball on the toolbar with a python command in a script but I don't want to disable the collection in the view-port entirely as it is used as a collection in a particle system.

I just want to deselect the eyeball circled in green below.

Anyone know the python API for this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can hide the active collection using the following code:

```
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.hide_viewport = True
```

If you want to hide more than the active collection you will have to iterate through the children of `layer_collection`

```
collections = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children

for collection in collections:
    collection.hide_viewport = True
```

Be aware that `bpy.data.collections` and `bpy.context.scene.collection` also allow to access the collections and set `hide_viewport`. However, since these do not depend on the active view layer, they apply globally and therefore activate *Disable in Viewports*.

Comment: Seems that `bpy.context.collection` is a reference to the *active* collection as well...?

Comment: Yes, but `hide_viewport` will act like *Disable in Viewports* for that one as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works to hide the active collection. Unfortunately Now it turns out the active collection is not the one I am trying to hide lol. 

Any chance you know the code to make a collection in the scene active via scripting? Can't seem to find that anywhere.

Comment: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/set-active-collection/2409 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127403/change-active-collection

Comment: @BradHamilton If an answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the green check mark above left. (and or upvoting too)  (break your duck on both)  Questions without accepted answers are constantly bumped by the community bot.