# How can I check which of my collections are hidden in viewport?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Using this part of code...

```
for collection in bpy.data.collections:
    print(collection.name, ' - ', collection.hide_viewport)
```

...I am trying to check which of my **collections** are **hidden in viewport**. But the **result** I get in **console**, has to do with the **collection** where are **disabled in viewport**!!! Any idea what is the correct way?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155563/how-to-hide-a-collection-in-viewport-but-not-disable-in-viewport-via-script

Comment: I don't want to hide or unhide a collection but to check if it is hidden!!! Something like `hide_get()` for object...

Comment: IMO it's the same thing, see accepted answer, print rather than set.

Comment: I can't understand what you mean...

Comment: Seems there is no other option for now.

Comment: @brockmann So what I am trying to do is missing... For now at least.

Comment: Suggest iterate through the collections *in context* at least (see the link).

Comment: @brockmann what link?

Comment: The link in comment one. Please look at the accepted answer. There is a difference between `bpy.types.LayerCollection` (in link, the collections assoc with the view layer) ) and `bpy.types.Collection` in question)  See answer below.

Comment: The very first link batFINGER posted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looping collections through `bpy.data.collections` gives you classes of type `Collection`:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html#bpy.types.Collection

Looping collections through `bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children` gives you classes of type `LayerCollection`:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.LayerCollection.html#bpy.types.LayerCollection

The meaning of the property `hide_viewport` seems to be slightly different in these two class types.

- In type `Collection` it means: "Globally *disable* in viewports"
- In type `LayerCollection` it means: "Temporarily *hide* in viewport"
- Type `LayerCollection` additionally exposes the property `is_visible`, which is True, when the collection is both enabled and visible

I guess `LayerCollection.hide_viewport` is what you were looking for.

Code example to see the differences in action:

```
print('Looping type "Collection", property "hide_viewport":')
for collection in bpy.data.collections:
    print(collection.name, ' - Disabled in Viewport:', collection.hide_viewport)

print('Looping type "LayerCollection", property "hide_viewport":')
for layer_collection in bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children:
    print(layer_collection.name, ' - Hidden in Viewport: ', layer_collection.hide_viewport)

print('Looping type "LayerCollection", property "is_visible":')
for layer_collection in bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children:
    print(layer_collection.name, ' - Enabled and visible: ', layer_collection.is_visible)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!