# Having trouble properly adding object to collection using Python script

Tags: python, collections

I want to put some objects in a separate collection in my Python script.  However, when I add an existing object to a new collection, it seems to exist in both the new collection and the main collection (where I put it to begin with) as shown in this figure the Cube exists in both the axis collection and the scene collection:

[image]

Here is my script:

```
import bpy
scene_collection = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children[0]
new_collection = bpy.data.collections.new("Axes")
bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(new_collection)
obj=bpy.context.active_object
new_collection.objects.link(obj)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add()
#scene_collection.objects.unlink(obj)
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = scene_collection 
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add()  #add cone to original collection
```

The script adds the initial cube that appears in the 3D view to the new collection.  When I was reading about collections, I was under the impression that new objects would automatically be added to the new collection, but the first cone that I add in the script is placed in the original collection.

So, my questions are, why is the Cube in both collections and how can I make sure it is only in one, and can I make the new collection active so that new objects are automatically added to it?

Comment: After I asked this question, I found a similar one in StackExchange's Related list off to the side (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192580/object-appears-twice-when-linking-it-to-a-collection?rq=1).  From this answer, it seems like I was missing that the collection needs to be assigned a view_layer (probably not explained properly) before objects can be added to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object appears twice when linking it to a collection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192580/object-appears-twice-when-linking-it-to-a-collection)