# Invoke the File Browser inside an Add-On but wait with the rest of the script until it's closed

Tags: python, add-on, file-browser

I'm writing an Add-on in which I create a new Collection and then invoke the ImportHelper to load an FBX file. After that I would like to process the loaded data.
My Problem is, that my script doesn't wait until the ImportHelper is finished.

I defined the Import Helper like this:

```
class ImportFBXData(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
bl_idname = "import_fbx.read_data"  
bl_label = "Import FBX"

# ImportHelper mixin class uses this
filename_ext = ".fbx"

filter_glob: StringProperty(
    default="*.fbx",
    options={'HIDDEN'},
    maxlen=255,  
)

use_setting: BoolProperty(
)

def invoke(self, context, event):
    context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
    return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

def execute(self, context):
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath = self.filepath)
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

I start this inside my Operator:

```
bpy.ops.import_fbx.read_data('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Everything in front of this call gets executed properly.
The File Browser comes up and I can select a file which is loaded properly.
Because the File Browser runs modal, everything after it's call runs immediately but there is no data yet. How can I make the rest of the script to wait until I select a file, the FBX conversion is done and the data is loaded in to Blender?

I don't mind if the UI is locked up until the conversion is finished but I definitely need the file browser to select the FBX file.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple at the end. Everything what needs to be done with the data which was loaded by the `ImportHelper` should be part of the **execute method** of this class.

The invoke method (in my above script) was not needed at the end:

```
class ImportFBXData(Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_idname = "import_fbx.read_data"  
    bl_label = "Import FBX"
    
    filter_glob: StringProperty(
        default='*.fbx',
        options={'HIDDEN'})
    
    def execute(self, context):
        # Everything what needs to be done before opening the file browser 
        new_fbx_collection = bpy.data.collections.new("New COllection")
        bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(new_fbx_collection)

        # Open the File Browser and Import the FBX File
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(self.filepath)
        bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath = self.filepath)
        
        # Everything what needs to be done after the file browser 
        ...
        obs = [o for o in bpy.data.collections[context.collection.name].all_objects if not o.parent and len(o.children)]
        for o in obs:
            ...
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

This way my Add-On works perfectly.

Comment: Hi. I have taken the liberty to edit your answer, corrected the code indentation and the context reference (bpy.context -> context) in order to make it a little clearer to future visitors. If you don't like my edit, just roll it back. Further reading: [What do operator methods do? (poll, invoke, execute, draw & modal)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19416/what-do-operator-methods-do-poll-invoke-execute-draw-modal) Also note that according to PEP8 variable names should be lowercase: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names hopefully nice to know...

Comment: Thank you for the corrections! I really appreciate it! :-)
As a beginner and without proper programming training it's very hard to write functioning code and such corrections help a lot to see my mistakes. (And hopefully learn from them... =)

Comment: The collection known as `bpy.data.collections[context.collection.name]` is `context.collection`  which I assume the idea is to use   `new_fbx_collection` so can simply use that reference.  Re setting active collection https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/155433/15543

Comment: You caught me... =) The part where it iterates on the objects, was the first part of my script and I copied it out from an internet example. The create collection part I made later and did not pay any attention to the copied code anymore. 
I changed it  to `obs = [o for o in bpy.data.collections[new_fbx_Collection].all_objects if not o.parent and len(o.children)]` now. Many thanks for the suggestion! Dumb copying is the first step to learn but now I begin to understand the actual structure behind the copied lines.